# How to fix "Could not find necessary SLF4j logging jars" with Jetty?

Tags: java, linux, solr, jetty

I'm using jetty 9 as my container and I want to run solr5 inside my container,I copied all the .jar files from solr/server/lib/ext into my jetty base lib/ext ,but it showing me this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to initialize Apache Solr: Could not find necessary SLF4j logging jars. If using Jetty, the SLF4j logging jars need to go in the jetty lib/ext directory. For other containers, the corresponding directory should be used. For more information, see: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging
```

I don't know where's the problem, is it possible that my lib doesn't included?how can I make sure about that? or is it because of priority of running the .jar files? 
thanks for your help:)
this is the output of --list-config:

```
Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.version = 25.45-b02
 java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info = mixed mode
 java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_45-b14
 java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
 user.dir = /ladan/app
 user.language = en
 user.country = US

Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.version = 9.3.0.v20150612
 jetty.tag.version = master
 jetty.home = /ladan/lib/jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612
 jetty.base = /ladan/app

Config Search Order:
--------------------
 <command-line>
 ${jetty.base} -> /ladan/app
 ${jetty.home} -> /ladan/lib/jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612


JVM Arguments:
--------------
 (no jvm args specified)

System Properties:
------------------
 (no system properties specified)

Properties:
-----------
 java.io.tmpdir = /ladan/temp
 java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
 jetty.http.port = 8082

Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 25 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

 1:   3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar

 2:                   8.0.20 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.0.20.M0.jar

 3:                      2.3 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.0.20.M0.jar

 4:                    1.2.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar

 5:                    1.2.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar

 6:                    3.1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar

 7:                 3.1.0.M0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar

 8:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

 9:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

10:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

11:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

12:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

13:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

14:      1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar

15:                      1.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar

16:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

17:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

18:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

19:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

20:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

21:          9.3.0.v20150612 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-9.3.0.v20150612.jar

22:                    5.0.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-5.0.1.jar

23:                    5.0.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar

24:                      1.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar


Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml

 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml

 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml

 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-plus.xml

 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-annotations.xml
```

Comment: Are you also using implementation of slf4j ?

Comment: @SercanOzdemir I don't know ,where I can check it?

Comment: slf4j is just an api already, a bridge for you to decide and use one of the log4j, logback, java.util.Logging etc. If you don't provide one of their implementation jar probably will cause some kinds of errors as you get. Check the folder of jetty /ext. If you have the corresponding implementation jar. Slf4j api's jar name is slf4j-api the other jar name should include something like blabla-slf4j-blabla-impl

Comment: @SercanOzdemir there's nothing inside my jetty/ext (jetty home!)

Comment: I meant here: lib/ext. The default jetty library path.

Comment: run `$ cd /path/to/jetty-base ; java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config` and copy/paste the output to your question.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I added the output :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable the `ext` module and put your slf4j jars in the `${jetty.base}/lib/ext` directory.

Eg:

```
$ cd /ladan/app
$ java -jar /ladan/lib/jetty-distribution-9.3.0.v20150612/start.jar --add-to-start=ext
$ cp /home/user/downloads/slfj*.jar lib/ext/
```

Comment: it's working! but it giving me another error:Starting Jetty: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
do you have any idea that what I should do?

Comment: I fixed the error with -Dlog4j.configuration=file/log4j.properties :) ,thanks for your help Joakim.